# Understanding sink drains with S trap / no trap

Tags: plumbing, venting

This is an >100yo apartment in the northeast USA. I'm on the third floor/top floor, and the kitchen sink drain appears to have an extended S-trap going into the floor. The piping seems to be done using 2" PVC after the sink coupling. Directly behind the kitchen sink is a bathroom, where the sink drain which goes directly into the floor, and likely shares a drain with the kitchen sink

I haven't encountered any sewer gases and even when changing a toilet did not encounter any bad smells even from an uncovered toilet rough-in.

Am I right in assuming that the whole building likely has a whole house trap? While the sink drains are not up to modern code, does the bathroom sink drain indirectly act as a vent for the kitchen drain? Meanwhile, with a large diameter 2" pipe is the kitchen drain acting as a wet vent, or at the very least reducing the likelihood of siphoning simply because of the size?

I want to add a garbage disposal but wanted to check that shortening the "s-trap" wouldn't significantly adversely affect the drain's venting.

[image: Kitchen drain]

[image: Bathroom drain]

Comment: Looks like a 1-1/4" tail piece into 1-1/2" PVC to me, which is pretty standard. Your questions can only be given guesses as answers. No, it doesn't necessarily mean there's another trap. Yes, other components may be providing adequate venting to prevent trap plug scavenging. Hard to tell from here.

Comment: And you may be able to put an air admittance valve off that cleanout if you do have venting problems. They don't usually meet modern code due to the risk of overflow, but they can help.

Comment: There's actually an IPC method for an approved S-trap setup. You might have it - the downpipe being larger than the trap is part of that method (which keeps it from siphoning and maintains the wet went to the trap seal.)

Comment: To clarify: On the one hand "S-Traps" so called are explicitly prohibited. On the other hand, section 917, "single stack vent system" allows for a system where the branh drais serve as the vents to the stack, under various length limits and 2 inch minimum for vertical sections. Which looks a bit like an S trap, but isn't, *technically.* Mind you, locally (to me) that method is part of the local changes to IPC, and explicitly removed from play.